# visual studio code (run Python file in terminal does not work)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

visual studio code,[image: screenshot] pressing run does not work on mac. Let say I want to print the word "Hello" and run the code print("Hello"), it will not be executed. I tried reinstalling python and visual studio but I could't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. Figured out that I forgot to select the *Add Python 3.8 to PATH* while installing. You can either choose to uninstall and reinstall Python and make sure to select the above option OR you can manually update the user environment variable for PATH and add the path to scripts and python like the following.

```
C:\Users\<addyourusernamehere>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
C:\Users\<addyourusernamehere>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
```

Answer (score 1):

When this happens to me, the Python interpreter borked and I need to press `ctrl + c` (abort) in the terminal a couple of times. It's still in the Python process and vscode is trying to input the run command into a Python process that's not actually a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For me, downgrading VS Code extension called Python helped.
[This shows where the option to install another version is in VS Code Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rDqV.png)

As for today, I had to go back to version 2021.11.1422169775
M1 MacBook, macOS Monterey 12.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Just go to uninstall a program from start menu in windows and uninstall python launcher then wait and then single click on python 3.8.7 or any other version and click on repair (some down from the top ) and then wait and them open vs code select interpreter in your file and it works now...